# WebDriver: Why latest versions of Eclipse and Selenium Server is not compatible with latest version of Firefox

Tags: eclipse, firefox, jar, scripting, webdriver

I tried to execute a script in WebDriver with following latest versions of Eclipse, Selenium Server and Firefox, only Firefox gets executed and script does not execute further:

1. Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
2. Selenium JAR selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0
3. Firefox 36.0.4 and Firefox 38 beta version

**However, when I used Firefox 32.0, Scripts runs completely.**

What could be the technical reason behind non-compatibility of latest Firefox version with Latest Eclipse and Selenium JAR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see here in the changelog. It seems that mozilla has rewritten some of there apis which is now not available but selenium relied on this.

[Changelog](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/CHANGELOG)

> ## v2.45.0
>
> Important changes in this release:
>
> - Native events in Firefox relied on an API that Mozilla no longer   provides. As such, fall back to synthesized events on recent Firefox
>     versions.

I have been looking for the latest firefox version supported. Other people have found the same problem and are rolling back to using v35.0.1 see [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/selenium-users/1538kj0fqk/firefox-36-compatibility-issue-with-selenium-webdriver-2-44-0)